# Let $\mu$ be a finite borel measure & $\nu$ a complex borel measure on $\mathbb R$ if $\mu (I)\ge|\nu (I)|$ then $\mu (E)\ge|\nu| (E)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb R$ and $\nu$ a complex borel measure on $\mathbb R$ if $\mu (I)\ge|\nu (I)|$ for every interval in $\mathbb R$ then for all $E\in\cal B_{\mathbb R}$ we have $\mu (E)\le|\nu| (E)$

this is homework , and i don't really know how to start. and it comes with a **clue**:

use the monotone class theorem and the fact that for every $E\in\cal B_{\mathbb R}$ we have that $|\nu|(E)=\sup\{|\int_Efd\nu|:g\in\cal {L}^1(\nu),|g|\le1\} $ and $|\nu|(E)=\sup\{|\sum_{i=1}^n\nu(E_i)|\{E_i\}_i\text { are disjoint and measurable} , \cup_i E_i=E\} $ (i think we don't need both)

I will be very happy for some help.